# javascript variable declaration in the if/else loop

Tags: javascript

I'm a very beginner in javascript.
I'm declaring the string variable 'hello' based on the if condition.
I want to print the variable 'hello' outside the if/else loop, how can I make this work?

```
var test = 4;
if (test > 3) {
    let hello = "hello world";
}
else {
    let hello = "hello gold";
}

console.log(hello);
```

I don't want this way

```
var test = 4;
if (test > 3) {
    let hello = "hello world";
    console.log(hello);
}
else {
    let hello = "hello gold";
    console.log(hello);
}
```

Comment: declare `let hello=''` at the beginning of the codes

Comment: You don't *declare* things based on an `if`; you use the `if` to decide what to *assign* to a variable that has already been declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just declare `let hello=''` at the beginning of the code:

As `let` variable have the scope inside the brackets of them `{ }`...

> The let statement declares a block-scoped local variable, optionally
> initializing it to a value.

Read More:

[What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

```js
var test = 4;
let hello = "";

if (test > 3) {
  hello = "hello world";
} else {
  hello = "hello gold";
}

console.log(hello);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare the `hello` variable outside the `if`. Doing this, it will be visible for both `if` and `else`

```
var test = 4;
let hello
if (test > 3) {
    hello = "hello world";
}
else {
    hello = "hello gold";
}

console.log(hello);
```

Comment: Nice!  I like the ternary solution.  For those who might not know which one I mean: `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator - Conditional (ternary) operator - JavaScript | MDN

Answer (score 1):

When you use `let`, the variable only exists within the braces (`{}`) that is was declared in.  You need to either do:

```js
var test = 4;
let hello;
if (test > 3) {
    hello = "hello world";
}
else {
    hello = "hello gold";
}

console.log(hello);
```

Or

```js
var test = 4;
let hello = test > 3 ? "hello world" : "hello gold";
console.log(hello);
```

Or

```js
var test = 4;
let hello = "hello gold";
if (test > 3) {
    hello = "hello world";
}
console.log(hello);
```